# VS 2010 Directory Structure

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

By default, Visual Studio 2010 sets up the directory structure such that the .vcxproj files are in a directory below the .sln file.

So, I have:

```
Project.sln
Project\Project.vcxproj
Project\Project.vcxproj.filters
Project\Project.vcxproj.user
```

I would like to change this so that the .sln file and the .vcxproj files are in the same directory, essentially getting rid of this extra "Project" directory.

Copying all of the .vxcproj files into the same directory as the .sln file doesn't work as it will still attempt to find the .vcxproj files in the "Project" directory.

Where can I change this under the VS 2010 project settings?

I have looked under the solution settings and **Configuration Properties - General** and **Configuration Properties - VC++ Directories** but I don't see any option for this.

Comment: You can edit the solution as a text file.  The path to the vcxproj file is in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I would like to change this so that the .sln file and the .vcxproj
  files are in the same directory, essentially getting rid of this
  extra "Project" directory.

Uncheck "Create directory for solution" checkbox in "New Project" dialog.

[image]

- Copying all of the .vxcproj files into the same directory as the .sln
  file doesn't work as it will still attempt to find the .vcxproj files
  in the "Project" directory.

It does work this way:

1. Remove project from solution.
2. Copy project files.
3. Add project to solution.